# Non-spring MyBatis sample project

Tags: java, mybatis

I'm getting started with MyBatis, so I'm looking a few good sample projects that use a recent version of standalone (non-spring) MyBatis to get a better feel for the technology.

The examples I keep finding so far either use outdated versions, or use spring.

Can anyone suggest a good sample project?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some of the useful tutorial/introductions are:

- A step-by-step DAO-XML based MyBatis Tutorial

http://hmkcode.com/java-mybatis-mysql/

- A sample project that shows the XML Mapper usage and library setup

http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/11/mybatis-tutorial-crud-operations-and-mapping-relationships-part-1.html

- Koans project that helps for discovering some key points

https://github.com/quux00/mybatis-koans

- Another sample project that uses annotations

http://java.dzone.com/articles/getting-started-ibatis-mybatis-0

- After a quick introduction, I definitely suggest to read the official guide that shows the majority of the tricks in using MyBatis

http://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/getting-started.html

Comment: Thanks. I already found the koans myself and they were very useful, but I haven't seen some of the other resources.